# Rails3 - ActiveRecord multi-value select on a has_many through structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm getting deep into ActiveRecord and have passed the limits of my expertise.

Basically I have a company model and each company has multiple keywords associated with it.  I'm trying to code a query that returns a list of companies with all specified keywords ( eg - Show me all companies with keywords 'Financial Services' AND 'Mutual Funds' )

Here's the model definitions

```
class Company
    has_many :comp_keywords
    has_many :keywords, :through => :comp_keywords

class CompKeyword
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :keyword

class Keyword
    has_many :comp_keywords
    has_many :companies, :through => :comp_keywords
```

I'm using the following query which works for a single keyword but for multiple keyword searches it's doing an OR rather than an AND selection.

```
kw_list = ['Financial Services', 'Mutual Funds']
companies = Company.includes(:keywords).where(:keywords => {:name => kw_list})
```

I've also tried putting this query in a loop and calling it each time with a single keyword rather than a list of keywords, however that did not work.

Any help from an ActiveRecord expert would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
companies = Company.all.select { |c| (kw_list - c.keywords).size.zero? }
```

Here, `kw_list - c.keywords` will give you an empty array if the company's keyword list contains each element in your `kw_list` variable. Otherwise, it will give you the keywords in `kw_list` that are **not** in the company's keyword list. Therefore, you want all the companies for which the `size` of the array is `zero`.

Comment: Interesting solution however my Company table has about 250,000 entries, so I need to have the solution run in the database

Comment: I tried digging further into this one, but I haven't been able to come up with anything that works. The problem is that you're going to need to join to the `keywords` table once for every keyword in `kw_list`, and Active Record doesn't really support joining to the same table multiple times unless you write a custom query. Sorry I can't be of more help.